# Difference between COOKIE and CLIENT scopes in ColdFusion?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, client, scopes

I have been googling, but haven't found an answer.

I understand pretty well what the `cookie` scope does in ColdFusion. But I'm not 100% sure about the purpose of the `client` scope or the differences between it and the `cookie` scope. 
It gets a bit muddy because one of the storage methods for the `client` scope can be set to `cookie.`

Can someone supply an example, or use-case, that illustrates what the differences are and when I would use one versus the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Cookie` scope persists the data as cookies on client's browser.  Keep it small as it is sent along Every freaking http request. :)

`Client` scope can persist the data on DB (or registery on Windows, BAD BAD BAD, but it is the default).  It is used often in a clustered env with non-sticky session, where a request might be routed to any server where Session data is not available.

I don't have the link, but you can read more on them in CF Dev Guide.

Comment: Also the `Client` scope is controlled by ColdFusion away from the manipulations of malicious users.  This is where you want to keep private information like the login status of a client.

Comment: @Paul - But does the Client scope do anything that the Session scope does not (which is where I would think to store authentication status)?

Comment: Also keep in mind that using the client scope will also force CF to send the tokens (cf tokens or JS session tokens) through the URL every time, since that is the only way it knows that your request matches the client storage item. It may not be an issue, but in some cases that is not allowed for organization security reasons.

Comment: We used client scope when we had our site running on a load balancer.  So if the user was knocked off of one server to another server, we'd know the status of their login.

Comment: The tokens are usual sent via cookie. The client scope does expire; however the expiration can be set to months.  The difference between client and session scope is where they live. Session is in memory only, while the client scope is persisted in a db. The contents of the Client scope must be serializable, while session can hold anything.

Comment: Let me check my understanding of CLIENT. It still sets its own browser cookies so that it can tie the user's session to the data stored in the CLIENT scope. Sort of like what a browser session cookie does for you along with the SESSION scope. So, if one is fine using SESSION, is there any reason to use CLIENT?

Comment: correct, use SESSION where you can, and CLIENT where SESSION is not sufficient. :)